# Dynamically render select options in Angular directive and transclude the default choice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an external RESTful data source that I am using to create options in various select boxes, something like this:

```
<div data-ng-app="app">
    <custom-select ng-model="selectedValue" option-source="myCodes">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
    </custom-select>
</div>
```

I have written a directive able to successfully perform the lookup and populate the drop down

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('customSelect', function ($compile) {
   return {
     transclude: true,
     scope: {
         optionSource: '@'
     },
     restrict: "E",
     template: '<select ng-options="value.longName for value in codes" ng-transclude></select>',
     replace: true,
     link: function (scope, element) {
         //Note: This would be a lookup, I'll just set the results
         scope.codes = [{
             "id": "F",
                 "shortName": "F",
                 "name": "FOREIGN MOVE",
                 "longName": "Foreign"
         }, {
             "id": "C",
                 "shortName": "C",
                 "name": "COAL",
                 "longName": "Coal"
         }, {
             "id": "D",
                 "shortName": "D",
                 "name": "DUMMY SCHEDULES",
                 "longName": "Dummy Schedule"
         }];
     }
   };
});
```

What I am unable to do is allow the user of the directive to pass the default option in the body of the directive tag without Angular adding a default "blank" selection.  [Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/swicklund/fpdhax7h/)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather put everything in your `option-source`. I have had problems adding option tags after `ng-options`.

Comment: The problem is, I have several screens that I want to use this directive, some require the "all", others do not, even for the same set of codes (options).  It is far more clear to have the directive behave as similarly to the standard Angular select as possible.